Mapbox - Error: There is already a source with this ID
All of a sudden I am geting this error with mapbox gl js:  Error: There is already a source with this ID. The app has been working fine but today this error occured. How can I find what ID and what source?  Not much detail in the error.
== UPDATE ===
While the error message was super vague, I believe I was able to find the source that I was trying to add twice.  In my code, I have the following:
    map.addSource('mapbox-dem', {
        'type': 'raster-dem',
        'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1',
        'tileSize': 512,
        'maxzoom': 14
    });

In another location of the code, I loaded a map style as follows;
// add a styled map to the contianer id map
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container:  'map', // container ID
    // fs satelite streets
    style: 'mapbox://styles/username/cll0bnk3u003t01r8ctcj7bmd',
   
    maxBounds:  INITIAL_BOUNDS,    // Set the map's geographical boundaries.
    zoom:       INITIAL_ZOOM,
    hash:       true,
    center:     INITIAL_CENTER,    // starting position [lng, lat] // dunlinhills location
    pitch:      INITIAL_PITCH,      // between 0 and 85 degrees.  0 is straight down.   
    bearing:    INITIAL_BEARING,    // The desired bearing in degrees. The bearing is the compass direction that is "up".
                                    // For example, bearing: 90 orients the map so that east is up.
    customAttribution: 'Map by me!'
});

When I look into the online style that I created with mapbox, I see that "Mapbox Terrain-DEM v1" is already included.  If I make a new mapstyle without "Mapbox Terrain-DEM v1" it seems to almost work, however, I would like to keet the current style and remove ""Mapbox Terrain-DEM v1" instead.  How is it possible to remove "
"Mapbox Terrain-DEM v1" from the map style.  Here is a snapshot of my screen (I have underlined that DEM in blue which I would like to remove):

